# How can i access a object from inside my actionPerformed JButton method?

Tags: java, swing, object

I want to create the `JButton` for my game, *Whack a mole*, with a standard icon set. This is the code for my `JButton`:

```
JButton btnMole1 = new JButton("");
btnMole1.setBackground(new Color(102, 204, 102));
btnMole1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/huegel.png")));
btnMole1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)   {
        System.out.println("Button 1");
        boolean mole1show = mole1.getShow();
        if(mole1show==true) {
            Score.erhoeheScore();
            btnMole1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/huegel.png")));
            mole1.hide();
            System.out.println(mole1show);
        }
        else {
            Score.senkenScore();
        }
    }
});
```

This is my code in my `Mole` class:
(I'm making a *Whack a mole* game.)

```
package Spiel;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Mole {
    private  boolean show;
    
    Mole mole1 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole2 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole3 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole4 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole5 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole6 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole7 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole8 = new Mole(false);
    Mole mole9 = new Mole(false);

    public Mole(boolean show) {
        this.show = show;
    }

    public void zeichneMaulwurf() {

    }

    public void show() {
        show = true;
    }

    public void hide() {
        show=false;
    }

    public boolean getShow() {
        return show;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't get access to my `Mole` objects inside the `actionPerformed` method. Is there any way to create the `Mole` objects in a way to be able to interact with it from the `actionPerformed` method?

Another similar problem I have is that I can´t access the `btnMole1` object outside of the `GUI_Spiel()` class to change its picture, which I would like to do in the `hide()` and `show()` methods instead of the `actionPerformed` method. I am quite new to Java, but all my other GUI aspects of this program work so far.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] - it will be easier to understand the structure of your problem. As a general recommendation, you should become familiar with [Model-View-Controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/) and [Observer Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) concpets

Comment: You don't create the `Mole` instances inside the `Mole` class.  Create an array or `java.util.List` of `Mole` instances in a different class.